# Stream returns object only if first element of list is equal

Tags: java, search, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I got simple data structure

```
private InMemoryDataBase() {
    Account account1 = new Account("222", "222");
    account1.getPlayers().add(new Player("john"));
    account1.getPlayers().add(new Player("rachel"));
    Account account2 = new Account("111", "111");
    account2.getPlayers().add(new Player("max"));
    accounts.add(account1);
    accounts.add(account2);
}

public class Account {
    private String accountNumber;
    private String password;
    private List<Player> players;

    public Account(String accountNumber, String password){
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.password = password;
        players = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

And method that finds `Account` if exists

```
 private Optional<Account> findAccount() {
        return dataBase.getAccounts()
                .stream().findAny()
                .filter(a -> a.getAccountNumber()
                        .equals(inputData.getAccountNumber()));
    }
```

and then simple logic involved with this

```
public void process() {
        Optional<Account> account = findAccount();
        if(account.isPresent()) {
           if(validatePassword(account.get().getPassword())) {               
               outputData = new PlayersList(ConnectionInfo.Source.SERVER, inputData.getSourceID(), players);
           } else {
               outputData = new Message(ConnectionInfo.Source.SERVER, inputData.getSourceID(), "Incorrect password");
           }
        } else {
            outputData = new Message(ConnectionInfo.Source.SERVER, inputData.getSourceID(), "Account not found");
        }
    }
```

Long story short, that's part of Client-Server communication, `inputData` is data sent from Client application. And it seems to work, but only if I enter accountNumber equal to "222" (first one in `InMemoryDataBase.accounts`.

I'v did some testing, I can switch those values in my data base, I'll get positive result only if I request the first one in the list. The other one ends up with message "Account not found".

Comment: Looks like a typo, I think you want `findAny` after the `filter`? Otherwise you're always filtering the first element of the list.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you should instead be doing

```
.filter(a -> a.getAccountNumber().equals(inputData.getAccountNumber()))
.findAny();
```

What you are currently ending up using is [`Optional.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) which filters in the only `Optional` you've got using `findAny()`, based on the predicate if the value exists.

Instead of which you should make use of [`Stream.filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) which filters in the stream of content and then you can use `findAny()` over it to get the `Optional` value.